# "Not allowed to load local resource" when trying to download file from network

Tags: html, file, browser, download

[server] is the name of one of the company's network
[myname] is my folder

I already tried a lot of Stackoverflow solutions, but none worked
The full path to the files is "\\server\myname\"

The folder is shared with everyone in the company and everyone has full permission

I tried all of the following, even with the download attribute

```
<a href="file:///server/myname/Test.txt">Download</a>
<a href="file://server/myname/Test.txt">Download</a>
<a href="file://///server/myname/Test.txt">Download</a>
```

Getting the following error everytime in Console without the download attribute

Not allowed to load local resource: file://server/myname/Test.txt

With the download attribute, I get 
Failed - Network error

Currently running my website on localhost with IIS and testing on Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think the updated Google Chrome default security policy doesn't allow you to open local files, follow this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-js/3kWYfpL55gQ).